# Better way to insert object with specific ObjectId() into MongoDB

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb, bson

I have a json representation of bson object from mongodb inside a test.json file.

In json:

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "560d34ce0699616af8b86842" },
    "siteId" : "Development",
    "description" : "Development Site",
    "lastModified" : { "$date" : "2015-10-01T15:27:42.884+0200" }
}
```

Or I can have serialized bson if needed:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560272fc0699610da8703eea"),
    "siteId" : "Develop",
    "description" : "Develop Site",
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2015-09-23T09:38:04.697Z")
}
```

What is a best way to insert this object with this specific ObjectId back into mongoDB with mongo ruby driver?

Now I have to load it, and update _id to BSON::ObjectId:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '192.168.56.52:27017' ])

sites = client[:sites]
sites.drop
sites.create
file = File.read('test.json')
y = JSON.parse(file)
y["_id"] = BSON::ObjectId.from_string(y['_id']['$oid'])
sites.insert_one(y)
```

Is there a better way to do this in ruby mongo driver? Since the representation of object is done by mongo, I was expecting some BSON::Object.from_string()

Comment: AFAIK, the "base" ruby driver has no knowledge of ["extended JSON Syntax"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) or any "bundled" utility that does such as thing. Specialized JSON parsers have been bundled that understand this syntax and do the type casting automatcally have been bundled with notably the Java and C# drivers for some time. You can always look  at [EJSON](https://github.com/primus/ejson) and forks to see how this handling is applied ( at least to some types ) and apply your own abstraction. Better yet, post some code that solves this.